# delete blocks of text between marks

Tags: vim

I have a large Rnw file with a large number of code blocks. I need to validate the code, and the text outside the code blocks gets in the way. I would like to automate the deletion of everything outside the code blocks. CODE BLOCKS are delimited by two <

```
<<name of block and options>>=
[R code block]
@
```

Is there an easy way to delete every line in the file EXCEPT the lines between '<<..>>=' and '@', inclusive? I can create a macro that deletes everything from '.' (current line) to '^<<' (beginning of code block), but this is tedious and error prone. Surely, this isn't the correct vimmish way to do things.

Thanks, CC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `:global`, but specifying the inverse ranges adds complexity to correctly match the lines at the beginning and end of the buffer. Since you presumably don't want to persist the original file with the deleted parts, just review it, I would do it the other way around: Grab the interesting contents between the markers, and put those into a scratch buffer for review. Using the usual trick of yanking to an uppercase register to append to it gives the following solution:

```
:let @a = '' | execute 'global/^<<.*>>=$/+1,/^@$/-1yank A' | new | put a
```

At its heart is the `/^<<.*>>=$/+1,/^@$/-1` range, which selects the R code block inside the two different marker lines.